# CSV blank values due to new line character

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm parsing a CSV using `Utilities.parseCsv()` but some cells have the new line character and at the moment I parse the value, it creates three different records out of one. Is there a way to remove `/n` to have it as a one cell.

**Sample CSV**

[image]

**Parsed CSV**

| id | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one Line |
|  | New Line |
|  | Third Line |
| 2 | one Line |
| 3 | One line |
|  | Second Line |

**Parsed Array**

```
[
  ["id","comment"],
  [1,"One Line"],
  ["","New Line"],
  ["", "Third Line"],
  [2,"One Line"],
  [3,"One Line"],
  ["","New Line"]
]
```

Ideally it would work if the array element comes like this:

```
["1","One Line     
      Second Line"]
```

but instead it is parsed like this:

```
["1", "One line"],
["Second line",""]
```

I don't have access to edit the original data

Answer (score 2):

I like to replace '\n' and ',' in the content with tildes of different lengths

```
function makeCsv() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let row;
  let a = vs.map((r, i) => {
    row = '';
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (j > 0) {
        row += ',';
      }
      row += c.toString().replace(/\n/g, '~~').replace(/,/, '~');
    })
    row += '\r\n';
    return row;
  });
  Logger.log(a.join(''));
  return a.join('');
}

function loadCsv() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const csv = makeCsv();
  const a = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  let row;
  const vs = a.map((r, i) => {
    row = [];
    r.forEach((c, y) => {
      row.push(c.toString().replace(/~~/g, '\n').replace('~', ','));
    })
    return row;
  })
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Personally, through most of my life I used `~~~` for data delimiters and `~~~~~~` for line delimiters.  Make like a lot eaiser.  It's not often you even see them in data.  But if you do they're easy to take out before hand.  If I had a customer that did want to give me better data, I'd just find another customer.

Comment: That definitely helps a lot. Thank you so much

Comment: @Irvin FYI, Code edits will usually be rejected.

Comment: @TheMaster This is noted, thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to replace values in strings.

```js
const stringWithLotsOfNewlines = `A
text with 
newline characters 
in it`;
console.log(`-- Before --`)
console.log(stringWithLotsOfNewlines);
const stringWithoutNewlines = stringWithLotsOfNewlines.replaceAll("\n", "");
console.log(`-- After --`)
console.log(stringWithoutNewlines);
```

Comment: I already tried that, once the csv is parsed, the new line is added as a new record, all the fields are filled with empty values.

Comment: @DavidSalomon try taking it out before creating csv.

Comment: @Cooper I'd love to, but that's the way the client sends the data

Comment: By any chance does the data in each cell get surrounded by quotes ?

Comment: the csv data doesn't have quotes, it's only when the values are parsed in apps script as strings.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the `.csv` data as plain text. Use Notepad++ or Visual Studio Code to open the file.